# extract last word from each line in shell

Tags: bash, shell

i have file result.txt which look like this:

```
acb.xyz.asd
mnt.x.sdr
s.ere.43
```

I want to write shell script which will extract the last word and print like below:

```
asd
sdr
43
```

I tried awk command but it didn't work:

```
awk 'NF>1{print $NF}' result.txt
```

I think i need to use delimiter "." and then parse the result.txt based on parse result. Plz help.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I usually use `rev | cut | rev` to extract the columns from the right.

```
 rev result.txt | cut -d. -f1 | rev
```

**rev** command in Linux is used to reverse the lines characterwise.

**cut** command in UNIX is for cutting out the sections from each line of files and writing the result to standard output.

- `-d` denotes the *delimiter* (here `.`)
- `-f` says which field(s) to extract (here the 1<sup>st</sup> one)

Answer (score 2):

You were indeed missing the `-F` option with `awk`

```
awk -F. 'NF>1{print $NF}' result.txt
```

Alternatively, you can use `cut` and specify both the delimiter and field that you want

```
cut -d. -f3 result.txt
```

Comment: In the `awk`, replace `$3` with `$NR` if you don't necessarily know how many columns are in the file (but you definitely want the last one). `cut`, unfortunately, doesn't have any such feature; you need to know the number of columns in advance.

Comment: @chepner you want to mean `NF`, since `NR` stores the number of record (that is, number of line normally)

Comment: Only if the number of fields is different from the number of records. Which is, like, almost always... :) Thanks for catching that.

Answer (score 0):

I think `sed -r -e 's/[^.]+\.[^.]+.//'` will do what you want.